# Round robin match location algorithm

Tags: algorithms, recursive-algorithms

*Although this is a software engineering problem, I feel like this is a mathematical question so wanted to ask it here.*

I'm trying to figure out an algorithm for setting a matches location for a round robin tournament.

- Each team plays each other team twice, once at home and once away.
- Each team has a home location.
- There are many teams in the tournament that share the same home location.

I already have access to an array of all the matches. A match looks something like:

```
date: "Thu Jan 08 2015 12:00:00",
home: "Bob",
away: "Frank",
location: null
```

I want to loop through all matches and assign the location. I've tried various solutions but nothing has worked perfectly yet.

- Of course, if Bob's home location is available on date we can just use that.
- We have to take into consideration the other match in which Bob and Frank play. It's fine to switch home/away teams but we must ensure it is balanced. (i.e. Bob and Frank play at home once each)
- If it is impossible to assign a location even after trying to switch home/away, we must then attempt *location splits*.

**Location split**

Match locations can be split so that multiple matches are played at the same time at a single location. How we determine if a location can be split is outside the scope of this question but let's just say we have a function called canLocationBeSplit(location) which returns a bool true or false.

Both home or away locations on either match between 2 teams can be split. However, we only want to start splitting locations unless absolutely necessary. Again, each team must play at home once and away once.

If there is still no available location for the match, we just leave it as null.

**Question**

So my question is, does anybody have any suggestions for a suitable recursive algorithm that would solve this problem? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Although I do understand the problem after reading your post, I am unsure what you want as an answer. Can you try to formulate a specific question you have concerning this problem?

Comment: @Hrodelbert You're absolutely right. I just added a question at the bottom, does that make it a little clearer?

Comment: @Fenna Yes, this makes it much clearer

Comment: Have you tried typing $$\rm double\ round\ robin\ scheduling$$ into Google, to see what comes up? Maybe if you find something useful that way, you can come back here to summarise it in an answer.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I have no problem with the scheduling round robin matches themselves. As stated above, I have all the matches already generated with dates but I am struggling with location assignments.

Comment: So you looked at everything that came up when you did that web search, and none of it dealt with the question of location assignments?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I did find one excellent post on scheduling that did take location into consideration but not in the sense of home/away that is in my question unfortunately. http://nrich.maths.org/1443